# Website Spidering Auto Detection

Tags: web-crawler

Is it possible to write code to detect if a website is spidering the content?

Answer (score 3):

a good spider

- reads the robots.txt
- has a proper user-agent
- will query faster than an average user

But a clear detection if it's a browser or a spider is not possible i think.

Answer (score 1):

You try using the user agent string to identify the bots.

Different bots seem to have different user agent strings:

http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

However, the user agent string can be easily spoof.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list of User-Agent strings that the common bots use. You can use some form of rate-detection and determine that a very high rate of requests will probably be a spider (or someone leeching your entire site).

There might also be lists of IP adresses used by common bots, but a fool-proof detection system is most-likely impossible.

You could create a link on your pages that a real visitor would never click and flag anyone that does follow the link as a spider. You will get some people clicking the link anyway but curiosity cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

If the spider is nice, you can detect it through it's user-agent using a list of existing user agents like [this](http://www.user-agents.org/). But a nice webspider usually also follows [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) convention

Robots that ignore the robots.txt file and spoof their user-agent most likely also use other means to hide that they are a spider.